# PostGIS selecting points using a subset of lines using ST_DWithin

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, st-dwithin

I'm not sure why this script sends a much higher count than the real number. This one sends 2314 points, which the answer should be 114

[image]

I can get the correct value by either dissolving all the selected lines or grouping the points based on their fid:

[image]

Can you explain the logic here?

Comment: If your first query returns many geometries from "practice_4.streets", then ST_DWithin can (and obviously will) find cases when the crime geometry is within distance of 457.2 units from streetA and from streetB and from streetC.. and all those pairs will make one row into the result.

Comment: please don't use pictures of text when simple text would work just fine.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question contain code as text. This makes it legible on all devices, searchable by others, and copyable by those who would be able to help. You also need to report the SRID in use